# Debug Eclipse Wildfly from IntelliJ

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, remote-debugging, wildfly-8

I have a local application running in local Wildfly that is configured using eclipse. I also have IntelliJ running in local. Now I want to run the application in Eclipse and connect remote debugger to it from my IntelliJ which is also running in the same machine. How do I do that?

In eclipse, I can see that the checkbox of **Attach remote debugger** is ticked and the port is 8787.

I try remote configuration in IntelliJ with **Host** as **localhost** and **Port** as **8787**, I get error **Error running 'Eclipse': Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8787): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect"**

Can some one help me with this?

**Why I need this setup:**

I have this application that is been setup on Eclipse since ages. As I am used to IntelliJ, I don't want to use eclipse. It will take some time for me to identify how to migrate it to intellij, so for now going with this work around.

Answer (score -1):

Ah, never mind. I added **-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8787** to launch configuration and it worked. I thought it appends these arguments automatically. But that is only when we use the bat file to start. Doesn't seem to be the way with eclipse.

**PN: I am not deleting this post as there may be others who would have similar requirement.**